# Showing that $\cos (\sqrt x)=e^x-2$ has solution in $(0,1)$

Tags: calculus, education

I rephrased this problem as finding a solution of $f(x)=e^x-2-\cos(\sqrt x)$ in $(0,1)$. I apply the intermediate value theorem:
$f(0)=e^0-2-\cos0=-2$. The goal is to show $f(1)>0$ (which is true) or to find some other number $c\in (0,1)$ for which it is obvious that $f(c)>0$.

However, $f(1)=e-2-\cos 1$. Without using power series expansions of $e^x,\cos x$ (e.g., explaining this problem to a student in differential calculus) how can I show $f(1)>0$? I tried reasoning using the unit circle to estimate $\cos 1,$ however it is not obvious that $(e-2)>\cos 1$.

Can someone suggest a nicer way to go about this problem (e.g., find a value to plug in that works better than 1 or explain why $(e-2)>\cos 1$ is clear?

Comment: So, what values you which values you want to find without series or computer: e, cos(1), sqrt(2), etc, and may I ask why? What tools are allowed?

Comment: The problem wasn't a good one since it's basically requiring them to memorize decimals. The reason for knowing the decimals is that it allows us to find an approximate to $f(1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Cosine is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$, and $\pi/4<1$, so
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\cos\pi/4>\cos 1.
$$
Can you take it from here?

**Edit**

Note that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx 0.707
$$
while
$$
e\approx 2.718.
$$
I assumed these (rather classical) approximate values were known.

Comment: Without a calculator I cannot. It's not clear to me that $e-2$ is larger than that radical.

Comment: It is wrong that $\cos (\pi/4)> \cos 1$. Sorry, it is correct, $1$ is not degree, radian.

Comment: $\cos(\pi/4)\approx 0.707>0.540\approx \cos 1$, so the inequality is correct.

Comment: @TheSubstitute: $\sqrt2=\sqrt{\dfrac{100}{50}}\simeq\sqrt{\dfrac{100}{49}}=\dfrac{10}7$

Comment: $(e-2)^2 \gt (\frac1{2!}+\frac1{3!}+\frac1{4!})^2 = (\frac{17}{24})^2 = \frac{287}{576} \gt \frac12 = \cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4}) \gt  \cos^2(1) $

Answer (score 1):

For lack of a better idea, use $\dfrac12=\cos\dfrac\pi3\simeq\cos\bigg[\dfrac13\bigg(3+\dfrac17\bigg)\bigg]=\cos\bigg(1+\dfrac1{21}\bigg)$, along with

$\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$, and $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\dfrac{\sin t}t=1$, implying that $\sin t\simeq t$ for very small

values of *t* $\bigg($such as $t=\dfrac1{21}$, for instance$\bigg)$. Together with $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$, we have obtain

the stunningly beautiful and mesmerizingly elegant expression $\cos1\simeq\dfrac{441+\sqrt{1327}}{884}$ . Now,

just like $\pi\simeq\dfrac{22}7$, we also have $e\simeq\dfrac{19}7$, which is very easy to remember, considering that it's my

birthday in the old Roman calendar, which started in March. If, however, the last statement might seem either too egocentric, or too European-centric, just remember that the Jewish calendar also has a [Metonic cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonic_cycle) of $19$ years, $7$ of which are leap years. If even this might sound a tad eccentric, or perhaps just a little too exotic, recall that [Leonhard Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhard_Euler), who discovered the constant, passed away on September $18$, or $18/7$, if once again we are to take into consideration the etymological interpretation of the names of the months of the Roman calendar. So you are basically left with proving that $\bigg(\dfrac57\cdot884-441\bigg)^2>1327$, which is equivalent to showing that $(5\cdot884-7\cdot441)^2$ $>49\cdot1327$, which is trivial.